# is my text positioning is stretching my website height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website for my university project and I am going through some issues regarding my text classes. For some reason my classes seem to have an odd height, resulting in a white strip appearing at the bottom of my web page.

```css
 #index-section div.index-title-quote{
      top: 165%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-bottom: -100%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    
    }
    
    #index-section div.index-title-quote h2{
    
      font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    
    #index-section div.index-title-quote h5{
    
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 13px;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
```

```html
<div id="index-section">
    <div class="index-title-quote">
        <center><h2>"Honour may not win power, but it wins respect. And respect earns power</h2></center>
        <center><h5>- Ishida Mitsunari, legendary samurai</h5></center>
    </div>
```

here is my code, thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: update: I think i have figured it out, I have added overflow, and have assigned it to "hidden". done the trick, but please let me know if there's a more efficient method. thank you

Comment: Your div is also not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a lot wrong with it. To begin with, your first `<div>` tag is not closed.

`<div id="index-section">`

Your text is white on a white background, making it impossible to see.

`color: #fff;`

Your div text is positioned 165% of the page-height away from the top, ensuring that it can't be seen at all.

`top: 165%;`

I've attached a snippet with these fixes

```css
#index-section div.index-title-quote{
      top: 10%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-bottom: -100%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    
    }
    
    #index-section div.index-title-quote h2{
    
      font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
      color: black;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    
    #index-section div.index-title-quote h5{
    
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      font-style: italic;
      font-size: 13px;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
```

```html
<div id="index-section">
    <div class="index-title-quote">
        <center><h2>"Honour may not win power, but it wins respect. And respect earns power</h2></center>
        <center><h5>- Ishida Mitsunari, legendary samurai</h5></center>
    </div>
</div>
```